# How to show different stocks from different sources and to buy from different sources.?

Tags: multistore, magento2.3, magento2.3.0, multicurrency, multi-vendor

[image]

I need to show the stock details like below UI and also to checkout from selected source. I got this stock details from database but I couldn't find correct way to display them.